# How to show an error in apple watch

Tags: ios, apple-watch

How to handle exception cases like offline error in apple watch, i can not find anything about this in Apple Watch Programming Guide.

Is apple watch support overlay text? or need make error ui by myself.

Answer (score 4):

WatchKit does not provide alert or error UI yet (as of March 2015). You will have to make one yourself.

One easy way is to make a custom class that implements *WKInterfaceController* and create the interface in Storyboard. Then use [`presentControllerWithName:context:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentControllerWithName:context:) to display it modally.

ErrorInterfaceController:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class ErrorInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet weak var errorMessageLabel: WKInterfaceLabel?

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context);

        if let dictionary = context as? [String: String] {
            if let message = dictionary["message"] {
                errorMessageLabel!.setText(message)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func closeModalView() {
        dismissController()
    }
}
```

Method to show the custom error UI modally:

```
private func showError(#message: String!) {
    presentControllerWithName("ErrorInterfaceController", context: ["message": message]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To display error text in your WatchKit app, you can use [label](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TextandLabels.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH19-SW1) objects.

Labels support formatted text that can be changed programmatically at runtime.

Comment: I believe context menus can only be manually invoked by the user via Force Touch, no?

Answer (score 0):

WatchKit does not provide any type of alert similar to `UIAlertController` you'd find in UIKit.

You can present a new interface controller and show details on that screen, then add buttons to it if the user needs to take action (for example to dismiss it).